# Event listener breakpoints in Google Chrome Devtools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Event listener breakpoints in Google Chrome Devtools offers various number of options, but for me, they are not really of great use since they always throw me to some irrelevant part of code.

What I would like to know is if it is possible to limit it to just one class? For example `onMouseClick` send me to the 1st method that executes after mouse click, inside specific class. If none of the methods are fired inside this class, than simply do nothing.

Comment: You can use [Conditional breakpoints](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints)

Comment: Well, if I knew where I should put breakpoint, than there would no be need for event listeners. One way would be putting breakpoint on every single line within file, but there must be better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the breakpoints for each script and each line individually.
First open the debug-tools and chose a script in the sources-tab:

[image]

Then you can click on the line-number (here only no. 1) and it looks like this:

[image]

As you see now is the line marked, but also in the right col your individual breakpoint is listed.

**After having marked the breakpoint you still have to reload the page that the scripts are executed again till to the breakpoint. Afterwards you can use the icons above the right col to step in or step over the commands following the breakpoint.**

Having minified scripts, breakpoints are hard to use, so it's better to have a script where each line has only one command, it's much easier then to debug.
So for debugging you should change the corresponding script in your page to the non-minified version, perhaps also with a map-file if available.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough. I know how to use google devtools and set individual  breakpoints, that's not what my question was about. I am asking about *Event Listener Breakpoints* (bottom right angle on both of your images). After I choose some of the options there, for example `onKeyPress` the breakpoint will really be triggeret on key press, but it always sends me to some part of the code which wasn't write by me, but which was generated.